# Google apps script in sheets. Progressively hide rows each week

Tags: for-loop, google-apps-script, rows

I have a [weekly planner](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13HkkMTuSTtTLK_ZXGdnnJPpt8YshUuAv-tlQkxm9XA0/edit#gid=0) (btw, free to copy, you can change the first date and it will change for the whole year).

**I need to hide 23 rows each week, so that it displays current week.**
First it would be 23 rows, next week would be hiding up to row 46, week after next 69, etc. I tried looping it with for statement within another for.

```
function hideRowsWeekStart() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Nedēļas_plānotājs');
  // Hides rows up to certain row (rowIndex, finalRow)
     
   for (finalRow = 1; finalRow <= 23; finalRow++)  {
     for(n = 1; n < 23; n++) {
        sheet.hideRows(1,finalRow[n])
      }
    }
}
```

but it throws this
[image]

Tried single instance of for and it hides 23 rows only.

```
for(n = 1; n < 23; n++) {
    sheet.hideRows(1, n)
}
```

It would have been easier to just delete the rows, since then the following rows would be just recounted from 1, but I need the rows hidden in case I may need look back and unhide them addressing uncompleted or WIP things.

Comment: The notation `finalRow[n]` means that the `finalRow` is array. But it's just a number. Number has no inner elements, you can't use `[n]` with a number.

Comment: But it eludes me how it's supposed to work. Do you want to hide/unhide last 23 rows above the rows of the current week? Try to describe your workflow more closely.

Comment: every 23 rows next week. 23, next would be up to row 46, next 69, etc.

Comment: How you will run the script? How the script will know how many weeks it's need to hide when you're running it?

Comment: I just set the trigger to weekly and run it from 11:00 to 12:00 pm. The dates are not the issue here. Hiding every 23 rows is.

Comment: The problem is, as far as I can tell, the script should remember (or calculate every time) how many rows were hidden at the lasts run. The calculations can be done different ways. In some ways the dates can be issue.

Comment: I'd propose the solution as follows: at every run the script will hide 23 unhidden rows from the top of your table. Is it Okay?

Comment: The last sounds correct.

Comment: And by the way, you can group any ranges of rows and then to fold/unfold the groups in one click. Probably it makes sense to try it as well. It can be done/undone manually and with script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basic code that does the work is here:

```
function hide_23_rows() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Nedēļas_plānotājs');
  var last_row = sheet.getLastRow();

  // get the last unhidden row
  for (var row = 1; row < last_row; row += 23) {
    if (!sheet.isRowHiddenByUser(row)) break;
  }

  // hide next 23 rows after first unhidden row
  sheet.hideRows(row, 23);
}
```

Probably it makes sense to make the function that unhides rows of last week. And to add these two functions into a custom menu. This way you can hide and show previous week manually any time. Let me know if you need it.

**Update**

Here is the extended variant of the code:

```
function hide_23_rows() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Nedēļas_plānotājs');
  var last_row = sheet.getLastRow();

  // get last unhidden row
  for (var row = 1; row < last_row; row += 23) if (!sheet.isRowHiddenByUser(row)) break;

  // hide next 23 rows
  sheet.hideRows(row, 23);
}

function show_23_rows() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Nedēļas_plānotājs');
  var last_row = sheet.getLastRow();

  // get last unhidden row
  for (var row = 1; row < last_row; row += 23) if (!sheet.isRowHiddenByUser(row)) break;

  if (row < 24) return; // no hidden rows on the sheet

  // show previous 23 rows
  sheet.showRows(row-23, 23);
}


// -----------------------------------------------

// custom menu
function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu(' Scripts')
  .addItem(' Hide previous week', 'hide_23_rows')
  .addItem(' Show previous week', 'show_23_rows')
  .addToUi();
}
```

It creates the custom menu 'Scripts' and you can hide and show last 23 rows via the menu.

[image]

Comment: Yes, I would also be glad to incorporate that kind of thinking.

Comment: And try to group rows. Perhaps the standart grouping will be enough, without hiding.

Comment: Also an interesting option, but by the time the planner is half a year through I would have about 26 rows starting from the top of the sheet (given that full year is 52 weeks).